# HttpWebRequest not responding suddenly

Tags: powershell, httpwebrequest, http2

I have been running a HttpWebRequest on a public website to return JSon for at least a couple of years. Last week it suddenly stopped working and would not give a response via this code (it is called Old because I am using a workaround with a powershell script, but it is a clumsy solution). It eventually times out after the default 100 seconds but a longer timeout would not fix it.

```
    Function CreateRequestOld(ByVal sMESUser As String, ByVal sMeeting As String, ByVal sRaceDate As String, ByVal iRaceNumber As Integer, ByVal iTrade As Integer, Optional ByVal sJuristriction As String = "VIC") As String
        Dim Url As String
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = Nothing
        Dim dataStream As Stream = Nothing
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim strResponseStatus As String = ""
        Dim reader As StreamReader = Nothing
        Dim responseFromServer As String = ""
        Dim sFile As String = "C:\logs\MESRaceLog_" & sMESUser & ".txt"
        Dim Util As New Utilities
        Dim sMeetingCode As String
        Dim RI As New RaceInfo
        Dim dte As New DateClass
        Dim dtRaceDate As Date

        If (iTrade = 1) Then
            sFile = "C:\logs\MESRaceTradeLog_" & sMESUser & ".txt"
        End If
        If (iTrade = 2) Then
            sFile = "C:\logs\MESRaceOddsLog_" & sMESUser & ".txt"
        End If

        Try
            sMeetingCode = RI.GetTABCouseCode(sMeeting)
            If (sMeetingCode = "") Then
                Util.LogMsg(sFile, "TAB CreateRequest Error no meeting code for Meeting name " & sMeeting)
                Return ""
            End If

            dtRaceDate = dte.ConvertStringToDate(sRaceDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
            sRaceDate = dte.Get_Date_String(dtRaceDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")

            Url = "https://api.beta.tab.com.au/v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/" & sRaceDate & "/meetings/R/" & sMeetingCode & "/races/" & iRaceNumber & "?jurisdiction=" & sJuristriction
            Util.LogMsg(sFile, "TAB CreateRequest URL " & Url)

            request = HttpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(Url))
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            request.Method = "GET"
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
            response = request.GetResponse()

            strResponseStatus = CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
            reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd()
            reader.Close()
            dataStream.Close()
            response.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Util.LogMsg(sFile, "CreateRequest Error" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return responseFromServer
    End Function
```

However, if I paste the URL into a browser (Chrome in my case) it responds with Json as expected.

So I tried Postman and it also does not respond if it is just the plain URL. If however, I copy the curl script and use Postman it does respond correctly. I notice with the curl script it has 23 request header elements, whereas with the plain URL (the one that fails) there are only 5 header elements.

I suspect that the website has changed to HTTP/2 and therefore requires all these extra header elements. So I copied the URL as Windows Powershell from Chrome (under developer tools, right click, copy as Windows Powershee) and created a script which is below and this runs well and grabs the response.

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$session.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_cs_c", "0", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_tgpc", "d077be37-9bfe-58ce-bb34-2219fe18534c", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("s_ecid", "MCMID%7C42816005962630671342879997247751714175", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_gcl_au", "1.1.1461016396.1701314243", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("__qca", "P0-115178265-1701314243095", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_fbp", "fb.2.1701314243684.710804252", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_scid", "173c7c5f-d2aa-4407-9b6d-5eb48d7d5326", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_scid_r", "173c7c5f-d2aa-4407-9b6d-5eb48d7d5326", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_sctr", "1%7C1706792400000", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("at_check", "true", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("AMCVS_5C750C3A53DB4D070A490D4D%40AdobeOrg", "1", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_abck", "E98C9DC841935F14412438E52AEE528E~0~YAAQBcfOF59EHWuNAQAAsVHf0gvjwuRSy0ElwTKYqvAoJLQPTUBCXrzWbnUSm592eN9RKleGSHb6N1G4sOpkqms4YYyspcf+3j26XCyZ5cUO/PtysyIwLocjO/mDFZ0aQTYZIcMXSuuNycWI0uarkBykoIE5TBfeo6kPD1jD7LecoSHOPVRT/z/FC/0XUS8QcgfqHESSh7Gk6D8Dh3OBQ67qpu6GXq2enMxvn/8v0vn9u0DfH739OwrQyIfO82L11CRPswZtzXj0Wk5Qx5z9ObdAZ+eM9Edz+ts4SjQVXm585PwP9aam/xPL6Lqhov+8+htIFbaKT9O9WoemaBfthkvFk90cFfZ4tv57iPDPwT7+dIDGIcwph6wK5gsd9DS4kCpPXiOIgDcJIV4r6/tL2h8xgm+Ui+Sx~-1~-1~-1", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("bm_sz", "55EEBE064EF9FD3569F82C5AE9083857~YAAQBcfOF6FEHWuNAQAAsVHf0had2HtUmx7KB2ZnSoNh2rj59HNbyA1TAzJCjLmz8aXSPpV1Q699Pfux/9L01gXAmWItcxkttXyzNTYJBwN5/0YXC7Z5KMVxPA4YnDI+DPEUDgbo9pls/PxE86j6qFbQsHPk5mjH5trCuBl4I6lLa4we6cHSZZ2D8Rb8hNSdi3hfkgNtXDISvW35NyOo3EMgBYkb3SZL5BgjWsI6D/Bw9rpj80MRJs/NPZPHOaCvj76NQEHEr2FNclSS1j5sKa3dCeLQC3CfFtw705FlSHX+fxLCaJr0k+V3guclD9JQxD64qzawCSqOur3H8sGNdd6eRHPULHeijC+naKplTbnYgTtwUX2KdjE=~3621429~4469301", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("AKA_A2", "A", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("ak_bmsc", "F23866DFAFE8CC0C588C07C641D011C3~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQOU5haKnFDcqNAQAAbNln0xZzvuAFiiDMoeSqPqgw/Qyd1vMSeWW1tBvtNwt1/1xz7GqrMaHlb6o/7sgtgmAm+DDYW43r4aLL0IpxZ2znjHkqMe9WUQGFW1z66zd5FWnbVJph+HPgdO38rC0bnaxlGp4EjsgLMVSp3JoveyRNFernNgur79/hEqApGaNw0wIdq+0uT1GIN7MzFitWaLYEXdbwgWmGYroXCzL4f2Jcxuz4jlsrvo+BhP36wRHKjmflq36j+D9bcg1E6QLT94auind7POTHnvh/uERvVKxGJdW6b4DpuHYiWo8s0EwK2PE2d3+7nXCH1iTxV7+2sDPmcMmqrPbGcrIH0UXR5bb7d2P64v4CgiynMUNx3AlK9JJBSm1czBQFKlMQ", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("www.tab.com.au", "179643557%7CMCIDTS%7C19777%7CMCMID%7C42816005962630671342879997247751714175%7CMCAAMLH-1709253617%7C8%7CMCAAMB-1709253617%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1708656017s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCCIDH%7C-394740951%7CvVersion%7C5.5.0", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("bm_mi", "7E78507F65544A6BEB911B6594252269~YAAQOU5haLLFDcqNAQAA1N1n0xaR8VACVmX0VDfQyabr26S83xcjsuZDySCB0Ba3KF8V7EBTrDO2I0q0LqCGVCXBIEpm4kqRUrsWAnZ2ku6pa3LWedJ/oPEPdqXXQz4MRQoqBv3xk/iKpQsEscblrzmKbEh1S+MoRjUsDv05k7V8/YypSTJlyfrhrA4XFBRJcyKThMUSgVmKmftm6lFi2Iv5X32BWk9tdClyDo1WcoR1gf3benLG+0dVsRJlJi3GhxxJh6NzUnbl5iuFh+p7VQtjevNJYtVX66OX773tSVIteUnl/rYsf5u/6dPm1F8FllaIkx0BtA==~1", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_cs_mk_aa", "0.1392149211434872_1708648818354", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("adcloud", "{%22_les_v%22:%22y%2Ctab.com.au%2C1708650618%22}", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_tguatd", "eyJzYyI6IihkaXJlY3QpIn0=", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_tgidts", "eyJzaCI6ImQ0MWQ4Y2Q5OGYwMGIyMDRlOTgwMDk5OGVjZjg0MjdlIiwiY2kiOiJkODhmOTQ2ZS0xNGY2LTU2MDUtODJlOS02N2FiZjA0NDQ0MzIiLCJzaSI6IjBhYzA0OGMzLTliZjgtNTBkZC04ZmZhLTQzY2U3N2ZkNGQ5MCJ9", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_tglksd", "eyJzIjoiMGFjMDQ4YzMtOWJmOC01MGRkLThmZmEtNDNjZTc3ZmQ0ZDkwIiwic3QiOjE3MDg2NDg4MTg1MTUsInNvZCI6IihkaXJlY3QpIiwic29kdCI6MTcwMTMxNDI0MjY2NSwic29kcyI6Im8iLCJzb2RzdCI6MTcwMTMxNDI0MjY2NX0=", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_gid", "GA1.3.286042675.1708648819", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_ga", "GA1.3.1084240241.1701314243", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_tgsid", "eyJscGQiOiJ7XCJscHVcIjpcImh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnRhYi5jb20uYXUlMkZcIixcImxwdFwiOlwiT25saW5lJTIwU3BvcnRzJTIwJTI2JTIwSG9yc2UlMjBSYWNpbmclMjBCZXR0aW5nJTIwQXVzdHJhbGlhJTIwJTdDJTIwVEFCXCIsXCJscHJcIjpcIlwifSIsInBzIjoiZjk5OWNmMDktNDlkOC00OTM3LTgyMmQtNzVkYWJhMzlhYjM1IiwicHZjIjoiMSIsInNjIjoiMGFjMDQ4YzMtOWJmOC01MGRkLThmZmEtNDNjZTc3ZmQ0ZDkwOi0xIiwiZWMiOiI0IiwicHYiOiIxIiwidGltIjoiMGFjMDQ4YzMtOWJmOC01MGRkLThmZmEtNDNjZTc3ZmQ0ZDkwOjE3MDg2NDg4MjE4MDU6LTEifQ==", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_cs_id", "8c885f2f-4ec7-a81f-a51d-0c7fbc4e5253.1701314242.13.1708649137.1708648818.1.1735478242634.1", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_cs_s", "4.0.0.1708650937050", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("mbox", "PC#4d529f94d644416b83c7f3f4420ea6c1.36_0#1771893939|session#e85cb33e18f1458fae30265336746b93#1708650999", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_uetsid", "1e537e60d1e411eeb9d3b9dc7b7b2ef3", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_uetvid", "fa7b46408f2e11ee94a259059b2087fb", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("bm_sv", "FA3401F77595CB3BFA48E9B3EB68D923~YAAQB1rWF90I/s+NAQAAvYR40xY/4Sg4442TcILWMORP16M+CUypxE/1Q8GoIPyAaR3Dw6QFQYepBzb6OzgAuHqjwVwgKffGPGlNSIakay0I67nwTvg22/n4RLbWrXHiKR1WUnyy0xS1ldQdlsQLEU9TbDrhJbIKxcuaoIvFSlWb13RSwFgigd6I77vhvfog4dYam2Prx93Z9S5AsP/Yt8mjF+UnQjukoloUsVSrB/tmd1rbngxGNFwKDA08xL7MVjU=~1", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("_ga_ZMHBYSQ22N", "GS1.1.1708648818.12.1.1708649915.60.0.0", "/", ".tab.com.au")))
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://api.beta.tab.com.au/v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/ThisRaceDate/meetings/R/ThisRaceCode/races/999?jurisdiction=VIC" `
-WebSession $session `
-Headers @{
"authority"="api.beta.tab.com.au"
  "method"="GET"
  "path"="/v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/today/meetings?jurisdiction=VIC"
  "scheme"="https"
  "accept"="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"
  "accept-encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "accept-language"="en-US,en;q=0.9"
  "cache-control"="max-age=0"
  "dnt"="1"
  "if-none-match"="W/`"850d3337bda07909d530fde6a483487e`""
  "sec-ch-ua"="`"Not A(Brand`";v=`"99`", `"Google Chrome`";v=`"121`", `"Chromium`";v=`"121`""
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?0"
  "sec-ch-ua-platform"="`"Windows`""
  "sec-fetch-dest"="document"
  "sec-fetch-mode"="navigate"
  "sec-fetch-site"="none"
  "sec-fetch-user"="?1"
  "upgrade-insecure-requests"="1"
} -OutFile Race.json
```

My question is how can I decorate the code HTTPWebRequest with all these 30 odd elements which are set with Powershell using the session.Cookies.Add command within code, and appear as items in the request header when run from a browser (or as a curl script in Postman).

I have tried adding a CookieContainer in my code but to no avail but maybe I didn't implement it properly. I never needed to set cookies in the past so my knowledge of how to implement them is limited.

I don't need a solution necessarily in VB.Net. I can change to C#. I only have VB.Net because of some legacy code and have not spent the time changing it all to C#

**Update 1**
I can now get this code to get a rsponse by adding a bunch of headers, the same as I find in the Powershell command.

This is now my code

```
'Using request As HttpWebRequest
        request = HttpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(Url))
        request.Pipelined = True
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        request.Method = "GET"
        request.Timeout = 5000
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"
        request.Headers.Add("authority", "api.beta.tab.com.au")
        request.Headers.Add("method", "GET")
        request.Headers.Add("scheme", "https")
        request.Headers.Add("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br, zstd")
        request.Headers.Add("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")
        request.Headers.Add("cache-control", "max-age=0")
        request.Headers.Add("dnt", "1")

        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
        request.CookieContainer = cookies
        response = request.GetResponse()

        strResponseStatus = CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd()

        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()
```

This will run successfully and return a response the first time, but I have this in a loop every 15 seconds. Sometimes the next loop will also work, but sometimes it won't. Sometimes 3 loops in a row work and then it fails and the next loop works. There is no consistency.

What am I doing wrong? I close the read stream so I don't think it is that. I am using just a single instance of the HTTPWebRequest and pass the object to this code.

I agree it is not HTTP/2 like I first suspected. It isn;t the timeout set to 5 seconds becuase even at 120 seconds it times out. When it works it takes milliseconds.

When it fails I've noticed the Pipelined is set to false, hence why I set it to true, but that seems to make no difference.

Comment: Why do you think server switched to HTTP/2?  There is no indication.  I suspect a cookie may of expired.  Try running working and then immediately the non working.  The working will update the cookies and maybe the non working will start.  What I think may be happening is the working code is returning GZIP which will run quicker than returning non ZIP.   So I would try to add the following header to your code : "accept-encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"  Your latest file may be larger than the older results.

Comment: Any luck resolving the issue? I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: It is bringing back Gzip and I  can get a response now after adding a bunch of headers. But after a successful reponse and if I run it again, it may work or it may not.

Comment: I believe i have solved the problem I was testing in PowerShell, but the code is using C# classes so it should be easy to translate into C#

``$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add('Accept', 'application/json')
$wc.Headers.Add('Content-Type', 'application/json')
$wc.Headers.Add('Accept-Encoding', 'identity')
$wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/120.0.0.0")
$content = $wc.DownloadString($url)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After at least a couple of days trying different options I have found a solution. So I am answering my own question.

What I have discovered is that when you send a request you need to provide a cookie container to receive the cookies when you grab the response. You must then send across that cookie container for the subsequent requests.

I have my request code in a function (VB .Net) and I was setting my cookie container as a new object each time I called this function.

I modified the function to take a cookie container as a parameter and created just one cookie container outside my loop, passed that across to the function each time. The first tiome the function is called, it populates the empty cookie container and then subsequent calls use the populated container.

Here is the code

```
    Function CreateRequestSimple(ByVal sURL As String, ByVal sAuthority As String, ByRef request As HttpWebRequest, ByRef cookies2 As CookieContainer) As String
    Dim Url As String
    Dim dataStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim strResponseStatus As String = ""
    Dim reader As StreamReader = Nothing
    Dim responseFromServer As String = ""
    Dim cookies As CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
    Dim expiredcookie As Boolean


    Try

        request = HttpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(sURL))
        request.Pipelined = True 'I don't think this does anything
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        request.Method = "GET"
        request.Timeout = 5000
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"
        request.Headers.Add("authority", sAuthority)
        request.Headers.Add("method", "GET")
        request.Headers.Add("scheme", "https")
        request.Headers.Add("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br, zstd")
        request.Headers.Add("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")
        request.Headers.Add("cache-control", "max-age=0")
        request.Headers.Add("dnt", "1")

        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip

        expiredcookie = IsAnyCookieExpired(cookies2, request.RequestUri)
        If (expiredcookie) Then
            request.CookieContainer = cookies
            cookies2 = cookies
        Else
            request.CookieContainer = cookies2
        End If
        response = request.GetResponse()

        strResponseStatus = CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd()

        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
    Return responseFromServer
End Function
Function IsAnyCookieExpired(ByVal cookies As CookieContainer, ByVal uri As Uri) As Boolean
    Dim cookiecoll As New CookieCollection

    '        cookiecoll = cookies.

    For Each cookie As Cookie In cookies.GetCookies(uri)
        If (cookie.Expired) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    Return False
End Function
```

I don't think I need to check if the cookie is expired because I think the expiry gets updated each time I call this function.

I call the function like this (psuedo code, not my real code)

```
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = Nothing
        Dim cookies As CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
        Dim sResponse As String = ""
        Dim sURL As String = ""
        Dim sAuthority As String = "auth.com.au"

        For i = 0 To 100

            sURL = "http://someurl.com/extra"
            sResponse = CreateRequestSimple(sURL, sAuthority, request, cookies)
        Next i
```

Thanks to jdweng for indicating that cookies were the primary issue.

Additionally, the site had changed to sending their response in GZip format, so I had to deal with that change as well. Once again thanks the jdweng for suggesting that issue